# Logstash config, “if message contains…”

Tags: filter, logstash, syslog

So, let's assume that I have a portion of a log line that looks something like this:

```
Dec 11 13:59:17 172.00.1.00 NPF_OLT_LAB05: clear service affecting Alarm for ONT "100002" at 2019/12/11 13:59:17.28: "ONT Dying Gasp"
```

And I have to create a filter that does something like this

```
filter {
  if ([message]) =~ "NPF_OLT_LAB05"{
   grok{
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{WORD:Alarm_Severity} %{DATA:Message} %{QS:ONT_ID} %{DATA:Time} %{QS:ONT_Message}" }
   }
 }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check with below configuration,

```
filter {
  if "NPF_OLT_LAB05" in [message] {
   grok{
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{WORD:Alarm_Severity} %{DATA:Message} %{QS:ONT_ID} %{DATA:Time} %{QS:ONT_Message}" }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yup this worked perfect, Cheers for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to correct a little bit. Try this

```
filter {
  if ([message]) =~ /NPF_OLT_LAB05/{
```